# How to use ScrollViewReader for iOS 14+ with deployment target of iOS 13

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

iOS 14 adds a new `ScrollViewReader` view that you can add into your views hierarchy under `ScrollView` or `List` to be able to scroll to a specific view by `id`. How can you add this when your deployment target is iOS 13 though, without duplicating your views hierarchy by wrapping it with `if #available`?

```
List {
    ScrollViewReader { reader in //FIXME: 'ScrollViewReader' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
        Section(header:
            Text("Header")
                .id(0)
        ) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ItemCell()
            }
        }
        
        //for an example
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            Button("Scroll to Top") {
                reader.scrollTo(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible with out duplicating your view hierarchy and using `if #available`, but I would be interested in the result if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a separate `ContentView` for the "innards" of your `ScrollView`, then you can use `if #available(iOS 14.0, *)` to selectively include a `ScrollViewReader`:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    ScrollViewReader { reader in
        ContentView()
    }
} else {
    ContentView()
}
```